# How to see PM2 logs of a process using PM2 API

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to get the PM2 logs in my backend server using PM2 API. I tried going through the docs but almost nothing related to logs.

I tried generating a pm2.launchBus but that only gets me current logs and not the old logs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for checking the pm2 logs:

1. run `pm2 logs (process Id)`
2. run `pm2 show (process Id)` and it would tell you the log location

Comment: Using the PM2 api for Node JS, not on the terminal. I want to show the PM2 logs on a web server.

Comment: This is useful for viewing the log on terminal

Answer (score 1):

May be not using PM2 API but a workable method would be read the logfile using fs and return to your client app

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API method to get the log data.  You can only read it from disk.  If you'd like to get more structured information about the log data you can configure the ecosystem (or process) JSON to either:

### Add a timestamp

```
{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "script": "main.js",
            "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which results in:

```
2021-07-30 06:34:22: Hello World!
```

### Write log entries as JSON

```
{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "script": "main.js",
            "log_type": "json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which will get you:

```
{
   "message": "Hello World!\n",
   "timestamp": "2017-02-06T14:51:38.896Z",
   "type": "out",
   "process_id": 0,
   "app_name": "app"
}
```

[See Log Management docs](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/log-management/#json)